# Add data-scroll Attribute to Kramdown Footnote

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

Is there an easy way to add an attribute of `data-scroll` to a kramdown footnote.

```
[Battlezone](www.github.com) [^1]
```

My footnote above, renders like so:

```
<sup id="fnref:1"><a href="#fn:1" class="footnote">1</a></sup>
```

Is it possible to add a that `data-scroll` attribute to the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to individual footnotes in the footnote definition.

```
This is some text with a footnote.[^note]

[^note]:{: .class #id other-attribute="attribute"}
    This footnote has some attributes.
```

Output:

```
<p>This is some text with a footnote.<sup id="fnref:note"><a href="#fn:note" class="footnote">1</a></sup></p>

<div class="footnotes">
    <ol>
        <li id="fn:note">
            <p class="class" id="id" other-attribute="attribute">This footnote has some attributes. <a href="#fnref:note" class="reversefootnote">&#8617;</a></p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to add an attribute to the the footnote button, rather than the actual footnote. Is this not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to do that. You can use the .reversefootnote class to modify all footnote buttons in CSS, but otherwise as far as I know you'd need to do some post-processing with something like sed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you actually want to write in the `data-scroll` attribute. But here is an example JS that will add those attributes to those links. Place this code before the closing `</body>` tag.

What you want is get every footnote link (only the links that return to the content), and then add attributes to all of them. This can be done like so:

### JS only

```
var footnoteLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("reversefootnote");
var i, hrefAttribute;
for (i = 0; i < footnoteLinks.length; i++) {
    hrefAttribute = footnoteLinks[i].getAttribute("href");
    footnoteLinks[i].setAttribute("data-scroll", hrefAttribute);
}
```

### jQuery

If you happen to have jQuery available, this is easier to do:

```
$('.reversefootnote').each(function(){
    var footNoteLink = $(this);
    footNoteLink.attr("data-scroll", footNoteLink.attr("href"));
});
```

If you want to set the `data-scroll` value to a value (e.g. all to `"true"`), the code becomes even simpler:

```
// JS only
var footnoteLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("reversefootnote");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < footnoteLinks.length; i++) {
    footnoteLinks[i].setAttribute("data-scroll", "true");
}
// jQuery
$('.reversefootnote').each(function(){
    footNoteLink.attr("data-scroll", "true");
});
```

If this is not what you were looking for, then surely this will give you a hint.